# Why can't inline functions see inside scopes?

Tags: c++

I understand that inline functions are functions whose bodies are inserted into the place at which they are called. Then why therefore aren't inline functions affected by scope changes when they are invoked:

```
#include <iostream>

inline void alert(const std::string &str) { cout << str; }

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    alert("Hello World"); // cout << "Hello World";
}
```

This doesn't work because I get the error `cout was not declared in this scope`, but if I do `std::cout` it does. Why doesn't C++ know that `cout` is a member of `std` if the function body of inline functions are inserted into the scope?

Comment: wouldn't you just change it to `std::cout`?  or put `using namespace std;` at the top?  Seems like better form to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior you are describing is a macro. Inline function is a regular function and it is up to the compiler to inline it or not. It behaves exactly as any other function with regards to scoping rules.

Answer (score 4):

Because it's a function, it has its own scope. Making it inline or not doesn't affect that. In fact the inline keyword doesn't change much about a function that's externally visible except its linkage. The compiler is free to choose whether to actually inline the code or not, inline is only taken as a suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Because C++ uses static scoping, not dynamic scoping.  The compiler looks up the name in the scope of where the function is defined, not the scope of where the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Inline-ing of functions is done during link-time. At compile-time C++ has no idea if at all the function is to fall within a scope. Thus the error is raised. Inorder to not recieve this error - well, you will have to make your inlined function a Macro instead.

Comment: It's really up to the implementation, but inlining can and generally is performed at compile time. It might also be performed at link time, but some linkers are "dumb" and can't do much in the way of code transformations, inlining included. That's why the standard requires that every inline function has a definition in each TU where it's used, so that there's no real need for link-time inlining.